# Issue while comparing dates in VBA?

Tags: vba

I am trying to compare two dates using the below code:

```
MsgBox (Format("07-12-2018", "dd-MMM-yyyy") > Format("31-12-2016", "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

Though the first date is greater than the second, the Message box displays False

Comment: Do not compare string representations of dates. Compare dates. Parse `"07-12-2018"` and `"31-12-2016"` into variables of type Date and compare that.

Comment: Because the first *string* isn't comparing as "greater" because 0 is less than 3, you're doing textual comparison, not date-based.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing strings, use the [DateValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datevalue-function) or [DateSerial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) function.

**DateValue**

```
MsgBox (DateValue("07-12-2018") > DateValue("31-12-2016"))
```

This will correctly display `True`

Note:

> DateValue recognizes the order for month, day, and year according to the Short Date format that you specified for your system

**DateSerial**

Is *independent* of the local system's Short Date format, since it uses separate arguments for the year, month, and date:

```
MsgBox (DateSerial(2018,12,7) > DateSerial(2016,12,31))
```

Comment: Or even better use `DateSerial(2018, 12, 7) > DateSerial(2016, 12, 31)` to make it independend from the operating system localization. `DateValue` needs the operating system date format to be `dd-mm-yyyy` to work with these string dates. If you use your code and the operating system is set to `yyyy-mm-dd` for example it will fail.

Comment: Good point, I'll add that to the post. A downside of using `DateSerial` is that you can't use a complete date string, it will have to be broken up.

Comment: You can **never** use a full string to convert it into a date (if you want it to be reliable result) because a string is lacking the information which part of the string the year, month or day is. Eg How can the computer know if `07-12-2018` is `dd-mm-yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy`? Computers cannot know it so that's the task of the programmer. You will always need to split the string into day, month, and year and use `DateSerial` if you not want Excel to start guessing.

Comment: True to an extent. I can imagine a UF with a textbox that would only allow values in a certain format. But then the programmer would be better off declaring the value as a date in another variable.

Comment: But the format that the textbox accepts must not be a "certain" format it musst be exactly "the" format that is used in the operating system. So if the workbook is used in more than one place (globalization) then this will still be tricky.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right. Not saying it would be ideal, but certainly possible.

Comment: @automaticSoldier has my answer helped you? If so, please accept it by clicking the check button just below the down vote button!